# How to Navigate from one View Controller to another using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, viewcontroller

I'd like to navigate from one view controller to another. How can I convert the following Objective-C code into Swift?

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navi animated:YES];
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38244058/1753005

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Create a swift file (SecondViewController.swift) for the second view controller
and in the appropriate function type this:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

---

#### Swift 2+

```
let mapViewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapViewControllerIdentifier") as? MapViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObj!, animated: true)
```

---

#### Swift 4

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IKDetailVC") as? IKDetailVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Comment: @audrey,Hi, how to set navigationController?

Comment: @Sanjivani, Hi your view controller can be created with Storyboard and  assign your firstViewController as rootViewController.Your navigation Controller (swift) class will look like this: `import UIKit`

`class SwiftNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // Custom initialization
    }``
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }`

Comment: How do you assign the first view controller as the "rootViewController" ?

Comment: Are you using storyboard ? what kind of project template do you have ?

Comment: I also had same problem, I was stuck at how to navigate from one ViewController to another. When I tried this code, I am getting this error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at second line of your code. Please help

Comment: I am having an issue with the animated: parameter like so: 
"Cannot convert the expression's type '$T7??' to type 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'".

Comment: You need to make sure your controllers are embedded in a NavigationController for this to work, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: @AkashRaghani did you set the Storyboard ID in Storyboard -> identity inspector ?

Comment: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Why have you removed the `?` from `self.storyboard`? don't you need to unwrap it?

Answer (score 35):

In my experience `navigationController` was nil so I changed my code to this:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardController") as! DashboardController
self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Don't forget to set ViewController `StoryBoard Id` in `StoryBoard` -> `identity inspector`

Comment: This is because your view controller wasn't ebbed in a Navigation View Controller.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want the back button to appear (which was my case, because I wanted to present after a user logged in) here is how to set the root of the nav controller:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewController") as! YourViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 16):

**SWIFT 3.01**

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Conversation_VC") as! Conversation_VC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 8):

In swift 4.0

```
var viewController: UIViewController? = storyboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier")
var navi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController!)
navigationController?.pushViewController(navi, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 10

Here **AddFileViewController** is second view controller.

Storyboard id is AFVC

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AFVC") as! AddFileViewController
self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

//OR

//If your VC is DashboardViewController
let dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DBVC") as! DashboardViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
```

If required use **thread.**

Ex:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AFVC") as! AddFileViewController
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

If you want move **after some time.**

EX:

```
//To call or execute function after some time(After 5 sec)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AFVC") as! AddFileViewController
    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let home = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HOMEVC") as! HOMEVC
navigationController?.pushViewController(home, animated: true);
```

Comment: i think it's not Swift or Objc syntax

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
let secondviewController:UIViewController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryboardIdOfsecondviewController") as? SecondViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondviewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 3

```
let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController        
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4 & 5 Users can use this way

> **Swift 5**

```
 let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

> **Swift 4**

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as? YourViewController 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let objViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Could you please explain shortly what your code does, why it solves the problem and how it's different from all the other answers.

Comment: here i am using storyboard id as identifier . Via the reference (objViewController) push the control to the View Controller   class

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Use Segue to perform navigation from one View Controller to another View Controller:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "idView", sender: self)
```

This works on Xcode 10.2.

Comment: type of segue ?

Answer (score 2):

**Better practices Swift 5.0**

More reusable and readable

Create a protocol

```
protocol Storyboarded { }
```

Now create an extension of the protocol

```
extension Storyboarded where Self: UIViewController {
    
    static func instantiateFromMain() -> Self {
        let storyboardIdentifier = String(describing: self)
        // `Main` can be your stroyboard name.
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifier) as? Self else {
            fatalError("No storyboard with this identifier ")
        }
        return vc
    }
}
// Make a ViewController extension to use on all of your ViewControllers
extension UIViewController: Storyboarded {}
```

**How to use**

```
  let vc = MyViewController.instantiateFromMain()
  //here you can pass any data to the next view controller. for example we have a variable with name `myString` in our next view contoller and we want to pass the data my `self viewController`
  vc.myString = "This string passed by MyViewController"
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**Note:-** You need to give the same identifier on the storyboard as your `UIViewController` class has. Check the example below

[image]

Comment: how to call this if it is extension of Storyboarded

Comment: @Pramod Shukla Confirm protocol `Storyboarded` on your ViewController and you will be able to use it. Or make a view controller extension something like this `extension UIViewController: Storyboarded {}`

Comment: @pramod-shukla I also updated my answer you can use it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

You can switch the screen by pushing navigation controller first of all you have to set the **navigation controller** with **UIViewController**

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourStoryboardID") as! swiftClassName

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate you can write like this...

```
var window: UIWindow?

fileprivate let navigationCtrl = UINavigationController()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.createWindow()

    self.showLoginVC()

    return true
}

func createWindow() {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: screenSize)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationCtrl
}

func showLoginVC() {
    let storyboardBundle = Bundle.main
    // let storyboardBundle = Bundle(for: ClassName.self) // if you are not using main application, means may be you are crating a framework or library you can use this statement instead
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginVC", bundle: storyboardBundle)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
    navigationCtrl.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update for Swift 5:

```
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Don't forget to update the Storyboard ID for both View Controllers!

Comment: you know, Swift is on version 5.4.