# Navigate to next scene in iOS Swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have been recently started learning iOS programming using Swift language. I managed to somehow put the elements on the page and interact with them. Now, in my sample application, I have a login screen, when user enters username and password, I send the details to my web service and get status success or failed.

I managed to show an alert when authentication fails. When success, how do I navigate to home scene or replace the current login scene programmatically. I have researched over the internet and found no solution. Please help

EDIT: 
I am using story boards on xcode6 beta

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038215/how-to-navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-using-swift

Comment: Are you using Storyboards, XIB files, or are you talking about SpriteKit scenes?

Comment: @Kamaros, I am using storyboards

Comment: @AlexanderW, That answer was not helpful to me, I am not using UINavigationController, I just want to replace the current login screen with home screen when successful login. Please help

Comment: I am a beginner and learning iOS programming in swift. Please tell me reason why i got downvotes, I am now banned from asking questios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on segues, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardSegue.html). In a nutshell, create a segue with a unique identifier between two view controllers in your storyboard. Then to execute the segue and move from the first view controller to the second, call `[performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`, passing the identifier you assigned to the segue as the first parameter.

If you wish to pass any data between your view controllers, you can do this by overriding `[prepareForSegue:sender:]`, accessing the source and destination view controllers via the `segue` parameter, and differentiating between multiple segues using the `sender` parameter and `segue`'s identifier property.

Answer (score 0):

Take a button, add action to it and add the below code.
The destination view is `UllasViewController`, replace `UllasViewController` with the name as you need in program.
Give the name in the storyboard identity for the view controller and paste the below code in your button action

```
@IBAction func btnRegister(sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller : UllasViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UllasViewController") as! UllasViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```