# Programmatically navigate to another view controller/scene

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

I got an error message during navigating from first view controller to second view controller. My coding is like this one

```
let vc = LoginViewController(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The problem is I always got this kind of error message

```
2014-12-09 16:51:08.219 XXXXX[1351:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/FDC7AA0A-4F61-47E7-955B-EE559ECC06A2/XXXXX.app> (loaded)' with name 'LoginViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2efcaf0b 0x39761ce7 0x2efcae4d 0x31b693f9 0x31ac1eaf 0x3191e365 0x317fe895 0x318a930d 0x318a9223 0x318a8801 0x318a8529 0x318a8299 0x318a8231 0x317fa305 0x3147631b 0x31471b3f 0x314719d1 0x314713e5 0x314711f7 0x3146af1d 0x2ef96039 0x2ef939c7 0x2ef93d13 0x2eefe769 0x2eefe54b 0x33e6b6d3 0x3185d891 0x4ccc8 0x4cd04 0x39c5fab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: You need to add a `LoginViewController.xib` file in your project. When you create `LoginViewController.swift`, make sure include xib is selected.

Comment: Try to add a complete new view controller and substitute `LoginViewController` and see if it works.

Comment: BTW, I'm using storyboard

Comment: Me too, I am using storyboard and used your code to load a xib file and it worked for me.

Comment: To access a storyboard in your code, you need to set its Story Board ID in your storyboard.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I already found the answer

Swift 4

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! NextViewController
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Swift 3

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: From within a ViewController, you can access the storyboard using self.StoryBoard

Comment: it hides the "navigation bar"

Comment: @Danny182 If you want navigation bar to show, use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)`

Comment: What if its have UINavigationController tag to UITabbarViewController how to push UINavigationController in that case?

Comment: It(Swift 4) presents the new view controller modally

Answer (score 50):

Try this one. Here "LoginViewController" is the storyboardID specified in storyboard.

See below

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I was surprised that Nurdin's answer was suggested to work (and it didn't) because it was just calling push. This of course LOOKS like it should work since we're dealing with the navigation controller

Answer (score 44):

XCODE 8.2 AND SWIFT 3.0

Present an exist `UIViewController`

```
let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Push an exist `UIViewController`

```
let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

Remember that you can put the `UIViewController` Identifier following the next steps:

- Select `Main.storyboard`
- Select your `UIViewController`
- Search the Utilities in the right
- Select the identity inspector
- Search in section identity "Storyboard ID"
- Put the Identifier for your `UIViewController`

[image]

Comment: True answer, i voted up but why we need "Restoration ID" ? I believe "Storyoard ID" is enough for this situation.

Comment: Thank for your feedback @yucelbayram A restoration identifier is a string that you need to assign to any view controller or view that you want preserved and restored. In my case, i use this field because i need for determinate function however if you isn't need it can you remove.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to navigate to Controller created Programmatically, then do this:

```
let newViewController = NewViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

If you want to navigate to Controller on StoryBoard with Identifier "newViewController", then do this:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 15):

**Swift3:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController("LoginViewController") as UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Try this out. You just confused nib with storyboard representation.

Answer (score 11):

You can move from one scene to another programmatically using below code :

```
  let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

  let objSomeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“storyboardID”) as! SomeViewController

  // If you want to push to new ViewController then use this
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objSomeViewController, animated: true)

  // ---- OR ----

  // If you want to present the new ViewController then use this
  self.presentViewController(objSomeViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Here storyBoardID is value that you set to scene using Interface Builder.
This is shown below :

[image: Screenshot for how to set storyboardID]

Answer (score 10):

See mine.

```
func actioncall () {
    let loginPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginPageID") as! ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)
}
```

If you use presenting style, you might lose the page's navigation bar with preset pushnavigation.

Answer (score 8):

Programmatically there are different ways based on different situations

1. load storyenter code hereboard nib file

   ```
   let yourVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController;
   self.present(yourVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
2. Load from xib

   ```
   let yourVc = YourViewController.init(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: nil)
   self.present(yourVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
3. Navigate through Segue

   ```
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your UIView", sender: self)
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the method for a xib, instead I needed the one for a Storyboard. Your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyCustomViewController") as! ViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

XCODE 9.2 AND SWIFT 3.0

`ViewController` to `NextViewcontroller` without Segue Connection

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)
```

or

```
let VC:NextViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do navigation between view controllers using code with the help of storyboard and storyboardId of the view controller.
This code is for Swift 3:

```
let signUpVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Is there any introduction or explanation you can think of for the code in your answer? Perhaps a first sentence like "I think you want code like this:".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the good answers above to set the navigation view controller on top of your screen on your app, you can add it to your **AppDelegate.swift** file inside the block as follows

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let vc = DetailUserViewController()
 vc.userdetails = userViewModels[indexPath.row]
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure try below steps,i think may be error occurs below reasons.

- you rename some files outside XCode. To solve it remove the files from your project and re-import the files in your project.
- check and add missing Nib file in **Build phases->Copy bundle resources**.finally check the nib name spelling, it's correct, case sensitive.
- check the properties of the .xib/storyboard files in the **file inspector** ，the property "**Target Membership**" pitch on the select box,then your xib/storyboard file was linked with your target.
- such as incorrect type of NIB.Right click on the file and click "Get Info" to verify that the type is what you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I Give you my code to make a transition. 
In this example the action is connecting to an UIButton. So don't forget to set it.
Don't forget to set the name of your ViewController in the `transition` method.

Don't forget to set your storyboard too. Your need to have one view per viewController. Connect each ViewController to each view in storyBoard. You can see on the screenshoot bellow

[image] 
[image]

```
class PresentationViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         var playButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

         let image = UIImage(named: "YourPlayButton") as UIImage?

         playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
         playButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2)
         playButton.addTarget(self, action: "transition:", forControlEvents:  UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
         playButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

         self.view.addSubview(playButton)
    }


func transition(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("transition")
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourSecondViewController") as UIViewController

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as UIWindow
    UIView.transitionFromView(
        window.rootViewController!.view,
        toView: secondViewController.view,
        duration: 0.65,
        options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
        completion: {
            finished in window.rootViewController = secondViewController
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building UI without drag and drop (without using storyboard)
and want to navigate default page or ViewController.swift to another page?
Follow these steps
1) add a class (.swift)
2) Import UIKit
3) Declare class name like

```
class DemoNavigationClass :UIViewController{
     override func viewDidLoad(){
         let lbl_Hello = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:self.view.frame.width/3, y:self.view.frame.height/2, 200, 30));
lbl_Hello.text = "You are on Next Page"
lbl_Hello.textColor = UIColor.white
self.view.addSubview(lbl_Hello)
    }
}
```

after creating second page come back to first page (ViewController.swift)
Here make a button in viewDidLoad method

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/3, y: self.view.frame.height/1.5,   width: 200, height: 50))
 button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
 button.setTitle("Go to Next ", for: .normal)
 button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
 self.view.addSubview(button)
```

now define buttonAction method outside of viewDidLoad() in same class

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) 
{
    let obj : DemoNavigationClass = DemoNavigationClass();
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
}
```

Keep one thing that i forget 
in main.storyboard there is a scene with a arrow, 
select that arrow and press delete button

now drag and drop a navigationcontroller and delete tableview which comes with navaigation controller.
select navigationcontroller press control on keyboard and drag it in to another scene on storyboard that is ViewController.
This mean that your viewcontroller become root viewcontroller 
hope this help you
Thanks
in main.storyboard , drag and drop navigationcontroller,

Answer (score 1):

```
let signUpVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
// self.present(signUpVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signUpVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: You need to add some content around your answer and explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0.3**

```
 @IBAction func registerNewUserButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        print("---------------------------registerNewUserButtonTapped --------------------------- ");

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterNewUserViewController") as! RegisterNewUserViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
```

**Change our Controller Name RegisterNewUserViewController**

Comment: It should be `storyboard`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
let signUpViewController = SignUpViewController()
present(signUpViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want full screen of the new page:

```
present(signUpViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "make sure you give id to screen")as! screenviewclass
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: You told me we have to add "Storyboard ID" to the viewController as this answer said. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift Thanks!