# Pushing Viewcontroller through navigation controller , Showing Black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I being searching this issue in stack overflow but couldn't get an exact answer to the issue, i being stuck in it for long time.
Mine issue is i'm trying to push a TestViewController through navigation controller. when i click the button the TestViewController is being load with navigation bar and the UIScreen is in black colour.

Code of **TestViewController**

```
import UIKit
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }   

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        navigationItem.title = "Test page"
    }
}
```

Code of Button

```
@IBAction func secondButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonPressedNumber = "Two Clicked"
    buttonTextColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
      let a = TestViewController()
      let b:UIViewController = a as UIViewController
      navigationController?.pushViewController(b, animated: false)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your TestViewController has Xib?

Comment: yes @MohammedShakeer

Comment: Then also same issue @MuhammadAdnan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - programmatically navigate to another view controller/scene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374759/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene)

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: yes...@MohammedShakeer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(`"storyboard id"`)

Answer (score 8):

You have not set the **background color** of your **view**.

The default color of the of UIWindow is Black. So if you have not set any other background colors in the stack they will all be transparent.

Not setting an appropriate background color for your UIViewController's view will also cause weird visuals during a transition.

Comment: I am setting the background color for the view.. but I still get the weird visual during the transition.. how to get rid of this?

Comment: can we change the default color of the UIWindow?

Answer (score 6):

```
let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! viewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure the background colour is set to white these days. 
therefore, if view controller is created programmatically

in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear for a white background colour

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`