# Getting black screen while transition to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I am trying to transit to another ViewController but it gives me black screen! There is my code:

```
                            if (content == nil) {
                            let sec: testViewController = testViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
                            self.present(sec, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
```

in Storyboard:
[image]

Comment: Try this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374759/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene

Comment: in Addition , You class name should start with Cap Later , `testViewController` should be `TestViewController`

Comment: @MikeAlter I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: I know this is not answer , I am just telling you standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Storborad give storyboard Id ex-->testViewControllerId and check UseStoryboard Id**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let testController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"testViewControllerId") as! testViewController
self.present(testController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Give Storyboard ID to testViewController from the Main Storyboard.**

```
if content == nil {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let sec: testViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! testViewController
    self.present(sec, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to try another way to programmatically present your destination ViewController. Try this one,

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
let myViewController: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<myViewControllerRestorationID>") //if you have the restoration ID, otherwise use 'ModalViewController'
self.presentViewController(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: now it is giving error I also tried in this way the error : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException