# How to switch to another view controller using voice control

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller, voice

I want to know to code on how to speak a specific wording using voice recogniser, then it will automatically switch to the other view controllers when it recognises the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide this task. 
First of all you should recognize user speech and handle some keywords. Please refer to [this article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/speech-recognition-with-swift-in-ios-10-50d5f4e59c48) or just google something like "speech recognition with ios".

Then just navigate to a new ViewController. This action depends only on your needs and can be achieved by many ways. For example [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374759/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene).

Comment: Thanks. So how can I navigate to another viewcontroller by voice control? Would it be fine if I set the code if the voice recognizer recognizes a keyword, then it will direct to a certain viewcontroller? And how about the codes for this situation? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please again carefully look at my answer above. I provided a link to the article, as well as possible ways for finding some code for your task.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the problem I have encountered is when I have the voice recognizer and different view controllers ready, what would be the code for according to some keywords, directing to other specified view controllers as I could not find the code from the links you provided.