# Switch programmatically from a viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios11

I'm trying to create an app which will switch programmatically from a View Controller to another. I've already tried to do that with this code:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EndViwController") as! EndViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EndViewController, animated: true)
```

But it turns me this error:

> [Cannot convert value of type 'EndViewController.Type' to expected
>   argument type 'UIViewController']

Also, when I try this other code:

```
let timeLineTableVC = EndViewController()
self.present(timeLineTableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It gives to me a black screen on the simulator and the EndViewController doesn't appear.

In the end, when I try this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EndViewController", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EndViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It gives me this error:

> [libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)]

Comment: You cannot pass class type to pushViewController method. it should be instance of a EndViewController

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN so how the code would be?

Comment: In UIStoryboard name you have to pass your storyboard name not controller name, Please cross verify once your storyboard name and controller name also you have to assign storyboard identifier in your  EndViewController look this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374759/programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN I’m sorry for asking this stupid question but I’m learning swift so I’m having a lot of problems

Comment: @Nilesh Ok, thank you so much!

Comment: @Mules please check your EndViewController "class name" and "storyboard identifier" and make "true use storyboard id" in UIStoryboard... i think you forgot to assign the name of class for your EndViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first bit of code doesn't work because `EndViewController` is a type. You should replace this with `secondViewController` that you declared above.

The second bit of code doesn't work because you are creating an 'empty' EndViewController type and not instantiating the storyboard view .

I'm guessing the third bit of code is failing because your storyboard isn't called "EndViewController" (unless you've renamed it). Try changing this to "Main" instead.

Comment: No problem, please feel free to mark as an answer if that does resolve your issue.