# Segues are not tidy

Tags: xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

When I create a new segue using the storyboard (ctrl+drag), it creates creepy lines on my otherwise tidy clean storyboard... I was wondering if there is any method to make them prettier

https://ibb.co/iHt9N8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with a lot of storyboard view controllers, you cannot keep your storyboard clean.

Don't use segues. Just create an instance of the storyboard view controller programmatically and push/present it. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41512221/4129517).

Comment: Thanks mr. green, I feel akward that you can’ Just reposition the segues to make your storyboard look tidy ... at the end is not different from a simple flowchart 

Comment: You can reposition the view controllers which reposition the segues (sort of)

Answer (score 1):

First off. It looks like you are using segues incorrectly. You should not be using segues to go backwards. You should use a segue forward and then dismiss backwards without segue.

Remove any segues that you are using to “go back”.

Next, if it is still too untidy. Separate your app into different areas and use a storyboard for each area.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm sorry but I started learning Swift on 12 of June this year so i don't know many of the XCode features. I'm learning a bit on every comment here :)