# setHidesBackButton not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my `viewDidLoad`, I have the below code to hide the back button. However, when implemented, this disables the back button of further `View Controllers` in the chain of which I segue to. I'm not sure, but this may be to do with how I structure my app (please see image - note that the `Navigation Controller` on the far left is connected to a `Tab Bar Controller`).

```
// Removes back button
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

I've also tried the following code, but this didn't work as well.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: false)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: false)
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: false)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

[image]

Comment: It may be a bit late now, but you should also consider splitting your storyboard into multiple storyboards. Navigating to and from ViewControllers programatically Also consider using R.Swift (this helps in so many ways). https://stackoverflow.com/a/27562874/2472466

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to hide the back button on the current screen you should only clear the `leftBarButtonItem`. If you hide the `backBarButtonItem` too that will be applied to the next screen's `navigationItem`. Does this help?

Comment: I tried setting `self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I've just tried `setHidesBackButton` on a navigation chain which works, but this makes other back buttons inactive

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes Can you provide a minimal GitHub repo with code which demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try

self.parent?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

sometimes the viewController does not recognize it's navigation Controller without self.parent