# How to user pushViewController page transition in mainViewController

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I want to implement transition of this like only in code.
[gif link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/965MA.gif)
But i seem not using the navigationController in the navigationBarViewController of Material.

So pushViewController method is not available for page transition?
this code is use [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material)

```
  import UIKit
  import Material

  /// MaterialCollectionViewDelegate methods.
  extension FeedViewController: MaterialCollectionViewDelegate {
      /// Executed when an item is selected.
      func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
          print(indexPath)
          // --------------------------------My Question--------------------------------------//
          let vc = DetailViewController()
          self.navigationBarViewController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
          // ----------------------------------------------------------------------//
      }  
  }

  class FeedViewController: UIViewController {
      private var collectionView: MaterialCollectionView = MaterialCollectionView()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          prepareView()
          prepareCollectionView()
      }

      override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
          super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
          collectionView.frame = view.bounds
          collectionView.reloadData()
      }

      override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
          super.viewWillAppear(animated)
          navigationBarViewController?.navigationBarView.titleLabel?.text = "Home"
      }

      /// Prepares view.
      private func prepareView() {
          view.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.grey.lighten4
      }

      /// Prepares the collectionView
      private func prepareCollectionView() {
          collectionView.dataSource = self
          collectionView.delegate = self
          collectionView.spacingPreset = .Spacing1
          collectionView.contentInsetPreset = .Square1
          collectionView.registerClass(MaterialCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MaterialCollectionViewCell")

          // To avoid being hidden under the hovering MenuView.
          view.addSubview(collectionView)
      }
  }

  extension FeedViewController: MaterialCollectionViewDataSource {
      /// Retrieves the items for the collectionView.
      func items() -> Array<MaterialDataSourceItem> {
          return [
              MaterialDataSourceItem(
                  data: [
                      "title": "Summer BBQ",
                      "detail": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                      "date": "February 26, 2016"
                  ],
                  width: 150, // Applied when scrollDirection is .Horizontal
                  height: 150 // Applied when scrollDirection is .Vertical
              ),
              MaterialDataSourceItem(
                  data: [
                      "title": "Birthday gift",
                      "detail": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                      "date": "February 26, 2016"
                  ],
                  width: 250, // Applied when scrollDirection is .Horizontal
                  height: 150 // Applied when scrollDirection is .Vertical
              )
          ]
      }

      /// Number of sections.
      func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
          return 1
      }

      /// Number of cells in each section.
      func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return items().count
      }

      /// Retrieves a UICollectionViewCell.
      func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
          let c: MaterialCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MaterialCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MaterialCollectionViewCell

          let item: MaterialDataSourceItem = items()[indexPath.item]

          if let data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> =  item.data as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

              var cardView: CardView? = c.contentView.subviews.first as? CardView

              // Only build the template if the CardView doesn't exist.
              if nil == cardView {
                  cardView = CardView()

                  c.backgroundColor = nil
                  c.pulseColor = nil
                  c.contentView.addSubview(cardView!)

                  cardView!.pulseScale = false
                  cardView!.divider = false
                  cardView!.depth = .None

                  let titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
                  titleLabel.textColor = MaterialColor.grey.darken4
                  titleLabel.font = RobotoFont.regularWithSize(18)
                  titleLabel.text = data["title"] as? String
                  cardView!.titleLabel = titleLabel

                  let detailLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
                  detailLabel.numberOfLines = 2
                  detailLabel.textColor = MaterialColor.grey.darken2
                  detailLabel.font = RobotoFont.regular
                  detailLabel.text = data["detail"] as? String
                  cardView!.detailView = detailLabel

                  c.contentView.addSubview(cardView!)
              } else {
                  cardView?.titleLabel?.text = data["title"] as? String
                  (cardView?.detailView as? UILabel)?.text = data["detail"] as? String
              }

              cardView!.frame = c.bounds
          }

          return c
      }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post some code on what you've tried thus far? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: That is using navigationController to contain a uitableviewcontroller. if you want to push the view, you may watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038215/how-to-navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-using-swift

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is was hard to understand.
so I was updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Material [1.36.0](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/1.36.0), there are two new classes, NavigationBar and NavigationController. NavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController, so all the features for pushing and popping UIViewControllers on the stack of items is the same, while getting the ability to customize the controller's look and feel with ease.

The example App project shows how to use this.

Comment: I confirmed, Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to embed your initial view controller in a navigation controller.

Then you can use,

```
let newVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewControllerIdentifier") as! DetailViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
```

As per the gif that you provided as example, the transition is happening from a tableview. So you can perform the transition inside the `uitableview` delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Hope that helps!