# Link the UITableViewCell label to next ViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created 2 TableViewControllers in one ViewController programmatically as :

```
// contents for labels in cells for tableviewcontrollers

let contents1 : [String] = ["One:","Two:","Three:","Four:","Five:"]

let contents2 : [String] = ["Six:","Seven:","Eight:","Nine:","Ten:"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    table1.delegate = self
    table1.dataSource = self

    table2.delegate = self
    table2.dataSource = self   
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        return contents1.count
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
    {
        return contents2.count
}
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",  for: indexPath as IndexPath )

    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = contents1[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = contents2[indexPath.row]

    }
return cell
}
```

My question is that , how can I programmatically link  "Four:"  label of first     TableViewController "table1" when selected to show up next new ViewController                without using Segue?

Comment: if you do not want to use segue then you can use NSUserDefaults and Create Delegate method

Comment: Mayank Patel @ Sir, I am beginner at Swift. Can you please elaborate the solution since I have given whole codes?

Comment: You want to pass data to next view controllor right ?

Comment: Mayank Patel @ Not data, just show up next ViewController after pressing "Four:" from table1 TableViewController programmatically.

Comment: you can push view controller  [Here how you can do] - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24038621/3800154

Comment: Mayank Patel @ Sir, I didn't ask about the content in this link, I need to show up New ViewController while pressing "Four:" of table1 ...,,and I need to show up next new different ViewControllers while pressing "One:", "Two:", Three:". By the technique of link , it shows up same ViewControllers while pressing "One:", "Two:", Three:"Four:".....

Comment: posted answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `UITableView's` [deSelectRowAt](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614989-deselectrow) delegate method to identify the cell selection after that you can proceed to next view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if cell?.textLabel?.text == "Four" { // you can use you indexPath to compare as well
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Mayank Patel @ Thanx Sir, It worked for self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)  but it didnot work for self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController,, animated: true) . It didnot push up to SecondViewController but i wanted to push with navigation controller as i need default Back button.Can you plzz help here ??

Comment: You have to embed your current view controllor with navigation controllor after that you were able to push in secondviewcontrollor

Comment: You don't need to check the cell against nill, if you do optional unwrapping

Comment: Mayank Patel@ Thanx, it helped me.

Answer (score -1):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = pets[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```