# How can I switch view controllers with code in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let SecondViewController = 
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, 
animated: true)
```

For some reason this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think "present" is what you are looking for rather than push..

You should just be able to write present(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: The code you posted will only work if `self` is in a navigation controller.

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work @use

Comment: Does navigationController exist? I see its an optional so if it doesn't exist it will just skip the line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Navigate from one View Controller to another using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038215/how-to-navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-using-swift)

Comment: You need to add the symbolicated crash log and indicate the line of code that causes the crash.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, 
animated: true)
```

with

```
self.navigationController?.present(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Edit: To avoid the optionals you should also do one of the following:

```
guard let navController = self.navigationController else { return }
navController.present(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or

```
if let nacVontroller = self.navigationController {
    navController.present(SecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Edit2: You should also avoid force unwrapping your SecondViewController using one of the above methods as well. Although that is not your current issue.

Comment: Hmm.. When you said it didn't work, what happened when you tried it? Can you elaborate a little? Ex: Did it crash? Or did it just not do anything? Edit: Does your app have a tabbar as a parent view? (Does the screen you are on have a tabbar)

Comment: @ReidBrown Check your storyboard to ensure that it doesn't have broken outlets, also check to make sure that the view controller is assigned the class "SecondViewController"

Comment: This is all happens when I click a button just fyi I don't know if that has any significance.

Comment: @ReidBrown Have you checked that your iboutlet connections are linked properly? If they are not this will result in a SIGBART.  Specifically check both Views, buttons, button actions.