# Navigating One View Controller to Another using Swift 5 doesn't work

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, swift5

Okay guys, now that I have fixed this because of your help,

the error has gone.

but the page won't move to the 'requirementVC', so the button when i clicked, it just doesn't do anything.

```
@IBAction func buttonOK(_ sender: Any) {

    let button = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequirementsVC") as! requirementVC)
    self.navigationController?.show(button, sender: nil)

}
```

Thankyou again, appriciate it!

Comment: your button's class is ViewController not a requirementVC, are you sure with identifiers?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038215/how-to-navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-using-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Navigate from one View Controller to another using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038215/how-to-navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-using-swift)

Comment: Have you set the storyboard controller class name requirementVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following...

```
@IBAction func buttonOK(_ sender: Any) {

  let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequirementsVC") as! requirementsVC
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Here `Main` is the name of the storyboard.

`RequirementsVC` should be storyboard id set in storyboard.

And `requirementsVC` should be the subclass of the `UIViewController`.

```
//Class name should always start with capital letter. So rename requirementsVC to "RequirementsVC"
class RequirementsVC: UIViewController {

    //class body

}
```

Comment: still having the same error here..
also, i already create the view controller by dragging it. so i already have one. i just want to go from one page to another programmatically

Comment: can you post the code of  the `RequirementsVC` class

Comment: just default code..

import UIKit

class requirementVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    }
    */

}

Comment: What is the "App"? is it your project name or custom class name?

Comment: "App" is my project name

Answer (score 0):

just set your identifier and class of viewController you want to go on in this code :=

```
    let addReminderVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddReminderVC") as! AddReminderVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addReminderVc, animated: true)
```

Comment: i did everything u said, i've set the storyboard id, set it to asction, & so on, it run fine but the only thing when i click the button, nothing happened. nothing change.

Comment: did you check for getting nil navigation controller by setting break point.

so, may be you did not Embed your initial Vc in NavigationController.